# SharePoint designer custom form link not working properly when added in quick launch

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, custom-form, quick-launch, classic-experience

I am using SharePoint Online classic team site. I have created a custom form with the help of SharePoint Designer 2013 that helps me to add item in SharePoint List. I have added the link of that custom form in the quick launch menu of the site. The link works fine when I open it in the new tab of the browser, but when I open it in the same tab it navigates me to the list rather than form that I have added it in the link.

I have also used a custom JS file to hide some fields or for custom formatting purpose within the form. Have also checked the links on the browser tabs i.e. same and new tab. I found out the difference that the link opened in the new tab is fine, but the link in the same tab has the **&viewpath=\ link to the form** appended.

for example -

- link in new tab - https:\\myspsite.com\sites\sitename\list\listname\myform.aspx
- link in same tab -
  https:\\myspsite.com\sites\sitename\list\listname\myform.aspx&viewpath=sites\sitename\list\listname\myform.aspx

I tried searching the issue on google, but I didn't find any solution.

Comment: What is the format of the link you added to quick launch? Is it same as `https:\\site\list\myform.aspx`?

Comment: @Ganesh Sanap I have edited the question with actual format of the link